# How to see if object is contained in an embedded NSArray, then grab the other items in the set

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I currently have a NSArray which contains many NSArrays, each containing a pair of NSStrings such like the following: `[["A", "B"], ["U", "A"], ["X", "Y"], ...]`, and I am interested first checking to see if it contains a particular object, and then grabbing the *other* paired object and putting it in an array.  For example, if I am checking for `"A"` in the above array, the result array would contain `["B", "U"]`

I know how to iterate over each array, but am trouble deciding how to grab the paired object inside the array... thanks!

```
for (NSArray *innerArray in outerArray){
    if ([innerArray containsObject: @"A"]){
       //how to extract the other object and save it to an array?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure that your data will have exactly the structure you describe, you can use the fact that inner array have exactly 2 element - so index of "other" element will be 1-indexOfYourElement:

```
for (NSArray *innerArray in outerArray){
    NSUInteger ix = [innerArray indexOfObject:@"A"];
    if (ix!=NSNotFound){
       id objectToAdd = innerArray[1-ix];
       // Do something with it
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better than @steves approach using the ternary operator. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSArray *innerArray in outerArray){
    // Get the index of the object we're looking for
    NSUInteger index = [innerArray indexOfObject:@"A"];
    if (index != NSNotFound) {
        // Get the other index
        NSUInteger otherIndex = index == 0 ? 1 : 0;

        // Get the other object and add it to the array
        NSString *otherString = [innerArray objectAtIndex:otherIndex];
        [results addObject:otherString];
    }
}
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way:

```
NSMutableArray* results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSArray *innerArray in outerArray){
    if ([innerArray containsObject: @"A"]){
        [results addObjectsFromArray: [innerArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if (![obj isEqual: @"A"])
            {
                [results addObject: obj];
            }
        }]];
    }
}
```